# Spring security integration with local database and Facebook authentication

Tags: java, spring, facebook, authentication, spring-security

i'm developing a website with Spring MVC and Spring Security and JAVA backend.
Actually it has an authentication process on local database with username and password.
Now, i have to add facebook authentication. The final solution should be like the authentication process of stackoverflow. The user must be able to choose between local authentication and Facebook authentication (with the option to share content of the website on his facebook profile).
I've seen standard js solution of Facebook, but it seems to be incompatible with spring security and local authentication.

Can someone help me, possibly with some guide or tutorial?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqNap.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/). First read the doc. Then search on google.
Or look at this github project https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples/tree/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! [This guide](http://sunilkumarpblog.blogspot.it/2016/04/social-login-with-spring-security.html) has been like gold.

Answer (score -1):

The web auth and the db auth are two separate issues.
I don't use spring but there are OAuth frameworks available that should handle most the work for you. http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/

For the database security that should be either set based on the backend connection string (for an app based login) or by using pass through authentication from the webserver handling the request. I would NEVER base DB security on facebook login info.

Comment: This may be a helpful example
http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: Spring social http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ is a better solution

Comment: I saw spring-social, but i can't get how to integrate with spring security and the possibility to choose between local authentication and facebook authentication. Do you have some tutorial or guide? @JEY

Comment: I don't know how to switch between local authentication and facebook authentication in the service that implements UserDetailsService